# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Build file '/Users/rajeevyadav/Downloads/sevendaystraventure/android/app/build.gradle' line: 58

Tags: android, flutter

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Cannot convert URL 'C:/Users/HP/key.jks' to a file.[The plugin `ext_storage` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
> To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
> If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
> Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/rajeevyadav/Downloads/sevendaystraventure/android/app/build.gradle' line: 58
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Cannot convert URL 'C:/Users/HP/key.jks' to a file.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLHlH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the key.jks file is in the correct directory

Comment: Can You please tell me where it should be?